# Two date fields in a form using jquery mobile for mobile web application

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

I want to add two date fields in a form in mobile web application. Based on the date selected on first calendar, the minimum date range in second calendar is set.
I am using jquery mobile but it does not provides a direct way to create a date field.
I found two options to create it : 
Datepicker by jquery UI 
Datebox by http://dev.jtsage.com/
Which one will be better which will help me to set the date range, change the css of the calendar easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First don't use jQuery Mobile data picker for jQuery Mobile, it lacks responsiveness jQuery Mobile needs.

Thankfully there are some 3rd party solutions made exclusively for jQuery Mobile.

**[Mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com/)** - http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/WDjfR/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $('#demo').mobiscroll().date({
        invalid: { daysOfWeek: [0, 6], daysOfMonth: ['5/1', '12/24', '12/25'] },
        theme: 'android-ics',
        display: 'inline',
        mode: 'scroller',
        dateOrder: 'dd mm yy',
        dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy"
    });  
});
```

**[Mobipick](http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/)** - http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/zyVjE/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $('#demo').mobipick({
        dateFormat: "MM-dd-yyyy"
    });
});
```

**[Datebox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/)** - http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ktbcP/

```
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "datebox", "useNewStyle":true, "dateFormat": "mm/dd/YYYY"}'/>
```

If you want to find more about jQuery Mobile date pickers take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/10-life-saving-jquery-mobile-plugins/)**.

**Mobiscroll** is best of them, unfortunately it is also a commercial application, or if you want to can use version from my jsFiddle example, at that point **Mobiscroll** was still free. It provides native like and feel skins.

Comment: I wouldn't advise it until jQuery Mobile 1.5, currently it is built from jQuery UI date picker and you will not have any support what so ever. If everything goes right it should be redone for jQuery Mobile 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile its self doesn't support any date popups it has been clearly said in this link[Jquery mobile datepicker](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/datepicker/).

In css wise  'http://dev.jtsage.com/ ' won't give you options but it will provide many options like disabling some dates of the month, highlighting dates of the months like wise. If you need css changes just override the properties and you will not have to change a lot because it keeps repeating the CSS for dates.